# Unable to connect to Oracle database from Weblogic server

Tags: oracle12c, weblogic12c

I installed Oracle 12c database server created the database using DBCA on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7. I can connect to the database using sqldeveloper on windows 7. I configured SSH Tunnel in putty. I start a putty session by logging to the RHEL 7 server. Then I start the sqldeveloper and login to the database. I have Weblogic 12c server installed on the same RHEL 7 machine and I am configuring a Generic Datasource to connect to the database on the same RHEL 7 machine and getting the following error:

Connection test failed.

```
Listener refused the connection with the following error: 
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:702)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection0(DataSourceUtil.java:371)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.access$000(DataSourceUtil.java:24)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil$1.run(DataSourceUtil.java:285)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:282)
com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:937)
com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:524)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
...
```

I don't see tnsnames.ora, listener.ora and sqlnet.ora files under /network/admin folder. I heard from someone that if I am working on the server there is no need to have those files. I tried to create listener.ora and tnsnames.ora file to see if it resolves the error. But, that didn't help. If I have tnsnames or listener files, I see the failure to connect from my windows machine using sqldeveloper as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well the error says the listener used in connection string used by WebLogic is not up or active. Check the output of `lsnrctl status` to see the listener is up otherwise the restart the listener `lsnrctl stop` followed by `lsnrctl start`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Listener is up. Here is what I see:
STATUS of the LISTENER
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Trace Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ip-10-122-55-57.internal)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "devstats.internal" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "DEVSTATS", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by replacing the SID with service name in connect string in datasource configuration of weblogic